# Обобщающие слова при однородных членах

Tags: пунктуация

Правильно ли расставлены знаки препинания при обобщающем слове и однородных членах? Смутило то, что у Розенталя нет примера с союзом "как" (или я не нашла), только "как то", "а именно", "то есть", "например".

Сейчас «...» выпускает такую продукцию, как: задвижки стальные 16-го давления, задвижки 25-го и 40-го давления, вентили стальные, клапана обратные, детали трубопровода (стальные отводы, переходы, тройники) — и это только малая часть.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Двоеточие после союза КАК не ставится. Можно опустить союз КАК и поставить двоеточие, но тогда смысл будет неточным.

Comment: Т.е. лучше убрать двоеточие? Сейчас «...» выпускает такую продукцию, как задвижки стальные 16-го давления, задвижки 25-го и 40-го давления, вентили стальные, клапана обратные, детали трубопровода (стальные отводы, переходы, тройники), и это только малая часть.

Comment: Да, нужно убрать. Тогда предложение имеет стандартную грамматику, только предупредительная пауза не обозначена. Но придется обойтись без нее, или надо перестраивать предложение (а это нежелательно).